# Screenshot by programming turns black - Swift

Tags: swift, image, screenshot, uiactivityviewcontroller, uigraphicscontext

I am trying to share a screenshot from my game through UIUIActivityViewController. To do this, I am creating a screenshot programatically and passes it through the UIActivityViewController.

The ActivityViewController seems to work. However, the image is all black.

Here is my code, were do I miss?

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view!.frame.size, false, 0.0)
view!.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

let shareViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image], applicationActivities: [])
MenuScene.parentView.present(shareViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The MenuScene.parentView is the GameViewController.

Comment: Off the top of my head, shouldn’t the number (third argument of the first line) be 1.0 instead of 0.0?

Comment: Hi, thanks for giving it a shot! Unfortunatly, that is not the solution. The other threads touching upon this issue says 0.0 will return an image with the same size in points as the screen, as well as Apple's own documentation. Despite this, I tried 1.0, but without luck as aspected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I changed the code to the following, with great results.

```
            let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, true, 0.0)
            yourUIViewController.view!.drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)

            let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

            let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [img!], applicationActivities: nil)
```

And of course, presenting the view.

```
yourUIViewController.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```